# Using multiple-inherited base class member names in derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, mixins

I have classes A1, A2, and B:

```
struct A1 { int call(int); };
struct A2 { double call(double); };
struct B : public A1, public A2 {};
```

Due to the name 'call' being shared by A1 and A2, the compiler hides those names in B, even if the signatures aren't the same.

```
struct B { void do_stuff() { call(int(0)); /* call? call what? *ERROR* */ } };
```

So then I go ahead and throw down some using declarations:

```
struct B { using A1::call; using A2::call; void do_stuff() { call(int(0)); } };
```

And everything's hunky-dory. But what if A1 and A2 have a lot of similarly named members, ex. A1 and A2 are specializations for some template class, and we want B to have the members of both under one roof? Then it ends up looking... well, very boilerplate heavy.

```
struct B {
  using A1::call; using A2::call;
  using A1::asdf; using A2::asdf;
  using A1::other_thing; using A2::other_thing;
  ...
};
```

I have to do this kind of a thing for tens of classes inheriting from lower-level class specializations. Is there any construct that would ease this keyboard tip-tappin' and readability hell?

Something like `using A1::*` if using declarations somehow supported globbing.

**Update:**

I've come up with a solution that recursively places using-declarations in a pseudo-variadic template hierarchy. It actually comes out really clean looking in the client code, looking something like this:

```
class B : mixins<A1,A2> {
  void do_stuff() {
    call(int(0)); // I'm not a compiler error!
    call(double(0)); // neither am I!
  }
};
```

I'll post the details as an answer if no one else comes up with anything.

Comment: Your design looks flawed. The compiler is trying to tell you that.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore This is the essence of mixins in C++, the only difference between this and textbook examples I've seen is that here I'm using overloaded function names as members of the mixins rather than wholly different names. What is it that you're finding flawed?

Comment: You can call member functions of base classes using their scope directly, you don't need `using`. E.g. `A1::call()`, `A2::call()`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I'm trying to avoid exactly that. The whole point here is that excess typing is avoided in user code. Imagine if A1 was a template class, part of a library, and its name looked like this: `node<void(int,int)>`, and A2 looked like `node<void(double,int)>`, and the member in question was `connect`. Suddenly everything is a mouthful. I feel I would be a bad library writer to force my users to employ that method.

Comment: What are you possibly trying to achieve by having a function that takes one argument of type int returning an int, and the same name function taking a double and returning a double? In general, the purpose of "mixins" is to provide interface functionality from multiple interfaces. If those interfaces have the same name, then you are in trouble,

Comment: @MatsPetersson Christ - why's everyone getting so hung up on the simplification employed to water down the problem to a bite-sized chunk? That was for the sake of example. It's a mixins library where members are overloaded with tags to determine which sigs/slots you want to use. One chooses the signals and slots by tag type; this makes it easier to enable/disable the overloads in different contexts, because you don't have a bunch of different names floating around to worry about and write traits classes for SFINAE purposes. It also makes it cleaner to declare the different sigs/slots.